# How can I format a block of text that includes line breaks using HAML?

Tags: jquery, html, newline, haml, line-breaks

Let's say I have a block of text that looks like this:

```
First line\nSecond line\nThird line
```

I want to take this text and display it (using a jQuery template) in HAML like this:

```
%li ${TEXT}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found any good way to have those line breaks actually display *as* line breaks. When displayed as-is, they end up being formatted (on the actual web page) like this:

```
First line Second line Third line
```

When doing your standard `replace(/\n/g, "<br />")` in JavaScript, the formatted result (post-HAML) becomes:

```
First line<br />Second line<br />Third line
```

In other words, the literal string `<br />` actually displays *to the user*.

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this problem; I'm just not finding it quickly.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery templates, instead of ${TEXT} where the TEXT property contains html, you should use {{html TEXT}}. This will prevent the jQuery template engine from html encoding your string.replace(/\n/g, "
") before inserting it into the template.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
- lines = text.split("\n")
- unless lines.empty?
  %ul
    - lines.each do |line|
      %li= line
      - unless lines.last == line
        %br
```

No doubt it can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the `\n` by doubling the escape (`\\n`)

```
replace(/\n/g, "\\n")
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear; I want to make the formatted output that the user sees actually have *line breaks*, not just a space, not the escape sequence "\n", and not the string "`<br />`". So basically I want HAML to either insert the actual `<br />` elements for me, or for it to allow *me* to insert `<br />` elements in the text I pass to it. Does that make sense? (I tried this answer, and the result is that the user actually sees "\n".)

Comment: in your haml view, use `%br/` for a break if you want to output a <br />  You may need to use some inline ruby (or use a helper) to replace the `\n` in your data to be `%br` course I dunno how HAML will deal with it in line since it is a bit picky about indentations for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Improved form of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259232/1781156):

```
- text = "Hello \nWorld"
%p= find_and_preserve text.split("\n").join('<br>')
```

(Although the question seemed to be more about `$.text` vs `S.html`, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898407/1781156).)